# Why my JYearChooser value when converted to a string value is always "1970"?

Tags: java, database, derby

I have used the same code logic from my JDateChooser to create a save button which will save my selected JYearChooser value into my derby database.

The first two date values can be successfully loaded into my database, however, when the year value is always "1970" when saved into my database.

This is my code for the save button:

```
private void Cmd_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         

    String 被审计单位名称 = txt_被审计单位名称.getText();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String 发票日期 = sdf.format(txt_发票日期.getDate());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String 报告日期 = sdf2.format(txt_报告日期.getDate());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    String 审计年度 = sdf3.format(txt_审计年度.getYear());


    String 被审计单位类型 = (String) txt_被审计单位类型.getSelectedItem();
    String 签字注册会计师 = txt_签字注册会计师.getText();
    String 备注 = txt_备注.getText();
    String 意见类型 = (String) txt_意见类型.getSelectedItem();
    String 已审资产总额_元 = txt_已审资产总额_元.getText();
    String 已审营业收入_元 = txt_已审营业收入_元.getText();
    String 收费金额_元 = txt_收费金额_元.getText();

    try{
        rs.moveToInsertRow();

        rs.updateString("被审计单位名称", 被审计单位名称);
        rs.updateString("发票日期", 发票日期);
        rs.updateString("报告日期", 报告日期);
        rs.updateString("审计年度", 审计年度);
        rs.updateString("被审计单位类型", 被审计单位类型);
        rs.updateString("签字注册会计师", 签字注册会计师);
        rs.updateString("备注", 备注);
        rs.updateString("意见类型", 意见类型);
        rs.updateString("已审资产总额_元", 已审资产总额_元);
        rs.updateString("已审营业收入_元", 已审营业收入_元);
        rs.updateString("收费金额_元", 收费金额_元);

        rs.insertRow( );

        stmt.close();
        rs.close();

        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM SHENJIWAIZI1";

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "项目已保存");
    }
    catch (SQLException err){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
        }
    }    
}
```

[image]

As you can see, my three most recent records have 1970 as the year value.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormt` expects the timestamp to format as milliseconds since epoch start (January 1, 1970 at midnight). Most probably your year choooser returns a value between 1970 and 2070, which `SimpleDateFormat.format()` interprets as about two seconds after midnight on Januar 1, 1970

Comment: okay...But I am still not sure how to solve this problem..

Comment: I don't know what the type of your database column is. If it is just a number (2016, 2017) or a string ("2016", "2017") then just provide an integer or a string value

Comment: True, pointless making it more complicated then it has to be. Thanks!

Comment: haha, I can just make a huge combo box with the recent 30 years included. Pretty sure my program wouldn't last that long :))

Comment: insert image , code formatting , removed chatty text